# How to dynamically adjust the number of rows in a table to pad table elements in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a balance sheet table. On the left hand side is all the assets and the right hand is all the liabilities.  There are short and long-term assets and short and long term liabilities. Currently my table looks like:

```
Assets                   Liabilities
  Short-term               Long-term
    Cash                     Bond 1
    Accounts Receivable      Bond 2

  Long-term
    Plants
```

The number of items under short/long-term asset/liabilities will change over time. So I'm looking for a solution to automatically adjust to the number of items I might have under each category. Is there a easy way in bootstrap to dynamically pad the column such that rows of similar qualities are aligned or do I need to pre-process this in Django first before outputting the results? like this?

```
Assets                   Liabilities
  Short-term               
    Cash                     
    Accounts Receivable      

  Long-term                Long-term
    Plants                   Bond 1
                             Bond 2
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="balance_sheet" class="container-fluid">
<div class="container-fluid col-sm-6 right-side">
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th> Assets </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ account_receivable_title }}</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
    {% for account_receivable in account_receivables %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ account_receivable.name }}</td>
        <td>${{ account_receivable.balance }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    <tr>
    <th>{{ account_plant_title }}</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for account_plant in account_plants %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ account_plant.name }}</td>
    <td>${{ account_plant.value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td>{{ account_total_name }}</td>
    <td>${{ user_asset_total }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
</div>

<p>
<p>

<div class="container-fluid col-sm-6 left-side">
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th> Liabilities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>{{ account_credit_title }}</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
    {% for account_credit in account_credit %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ account_credit.name }}</td>
    <td>${{ account_credit.balance }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    <tr>
    <th>{{ account_bond_title }}</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for account_bond in account_bonds %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ account_bond.name }}</td>
    <td>${{ account_bond.balance }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td>{{ account_total_name }}</td>
    <td>${{ user_liability_total }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>

    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't just target the results to the specific or desired table cell? Seems easier that way since you have both short and long term values for both assets and liabilities.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu. The number of items under short/long-term asset/liabilities will change over time. So I'm looking for a solution to automatically adjust to the variable number of items I might have under each category.

Comment: use col-*-offset or col-*-push. Or if it's a table, use colspan?

Comment: @dotty. How can you use colspan dynamically?  Would you be able to show a simple example?

Comment: You should post the HTML you're using.

Comment: From your HTML, I don't see the problem here, could you please clarify ?

Comment: @LorenzoPeña. I am asking how can you dynamically align the short-term or long-term lineitems, if the number of the line items changes?

Comment: I would definitely pre-process the data in the view, so that you can construct the HTML table directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest tables to get the alignment.

Looks like you're doing this:

[image]

You could do this instead:

[image]

Or even more nesting... Or use the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) (i.e. cols and rows) instead of some or all of the tables.